# projection map $p:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{T}^n$ locally preserves the volume

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, topological-groups

Let $\Bbb{T}^n:=\Bbb{R}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n$ be the $n-$dimensional torus.

Denote the projection map by $p,$ i.e. $p:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{T}^n.$

I am reading a document which say

*It's intuitive that $p$ preserves locally the volume*

> I am not sure why it's intuitive?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sure thanks

Comment: It's because of Fubini's theorem basically, that or the easy fact that $[0,1]^n$--the unit cube--has volume $1$ and Haar measures on compact groups are normally chosen to be normalized. See my answer for a more full development. In particular, I agree it may not seem as intuitive to someone without more background in the subject.

Comment: What's missing is that we're using the usual metric on $\Bbb R^n$ to induce a metric on $\Bbb T^n$ .

Comment: @TedShifrin why it's missing? If we define the volume as John Hughes we don't need that ?!

Comment: Well, without reading the entire document, I can't say from what the author derives his "intuition."

Comment: @Ted is saying nearly the same thing I did, but in a different way: when I said how to measure volume on the torus (by pulling back to a fundamental domain in $\Bbb R^n$), I was "inducing a metric" on the torus (or at least a measure...)

Comment: @TedShifrin It's a book which traverses many concepts of geometry without really going into details that's why I ask the question here. Thanks. (Marcel BERGER "géométrie vivant ou l'échelle de jacob")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that it wasn't intuitive at all.

Instead, it's probably more reasonable to say "The volume of a region $A$ of the torus is *defined* to be the volume of $Q \cap p^{-1}(A)$, where $Q$ is the unit cube $0 \le x_1, \ldots, x_n \le 1$.

With this definition, it's clear that $p$ locally preserves the volume."

Comment: Thanks, yeah with this definition it's intuitive. And so if the function is also injective it's preserves globally the volume?

Comment: I'm not sure what function you're talking about...$p$ is certainly no injective, for instance. In general, a function being injective doesn't mean it's volume-preserving -- think of the "scale everything up by 2" function on $\Bbb R^n$, for instance, which multiplies volumes by $2^n$.

Comment: yeah I was thinking about a function that preserves locally volume and being injective. Because if I am not misunderstanding Minkowski's theorem is much or less that.

Comment: @Alex as far as Minkowski goes, yes, but that's exactly one that builds on the topological groups model, which puts you back in the quite natural setting I describe where the intuition is much stronger.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want your Haar measure on $\Bbb T^n$ to be normalized, in which case it's quite intuitive because you know that the unit cube has measure $1$. This is in fact part of the definition of the determinant function as the "unique alternating, multi-linear form that takes the value $1$ on the unit cube."

Since our volume form on $\Bbb R^n$ is induced by the determinant it's natural since the space is homogeneous, so that if you have a set completely contained within a fundamental domain--or at least with points all from distinct classes in the fundamental domain--the measure is just given by the measure in $\Bbb R^n$. This is also borne out by Fubini's theorem,

> $$\int_{\Bbb R^n}1_S\,dx = \int_{\Bbb Z^n}\int_{\Bbb R^n/\Bbb Z^n}1_{\bar{S}}dh\,dg$$

The measure on $\Bbb Z^n$ being counting measure and the measure on $\Bbb T^n$ being the local Haar measure. Since $S$ only has representatives in one copy of the fundamental domain, the outer integral is trivialized.

Comment: Interesting answer, but not sure I understand it. You said "since our volume form is induced by the determinand" do you mean that the volume of a lattice (here $\Bbb{Z}^n$) is induced by the determinant? What is the Haar measure on $\Bbb{T}^n$?

Comment: @Alex Since you tagged the question "differential geometry" I assume you were familiar with differential forms, in this case the canonical volume form on the smooth manifold $\Bbb R^n$ is given by $dx_1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx_n$ which assigns the value $1$ to the cube. The determinant is the unique alternating, multi-linear form which does this, which shows the two are the same notion of "volume." The Haar measure on a group is the measure invariant under translation, so like Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$, it means the measure is the same even if you move the set around.

Comment: That's very interesting. Thanks for you explanation

Comment: @Alex no problem, if you haven't heard of these things before, I can see how it might seem less than intuitive to you! Haar measure is a critical object in the study of topological groups, and the idea that the set's volume shouldn't change just because you move it somewhere else is at its center. If you don't like that as much, I recommend leaning on the Fubini's theorem part of my explanation. The two are linked, but you don't need to know what a Haar measure is to understand Fubini. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of definitions and conventions. Both Euclidean space and the torus have (uncountably) many different volume forms/measures. However, as the torus is the quotient of Euclidean space by a discrete action, it may make sense, in this context, to equip Euclidean space with a volume form which is preserved by the action (there are still uncounatbly many of those). Doing so, the torus inherits a natural volume form which makes the projection volume-preserving.

Another way to reach the same result, is to start by choosing your favorite volume form on the torus, and then pull it back to Euclidean space. The pulled back volume form is automatically invariant under the action.

Anyway, "intuitive" is not the right word.

**Edit:** We now show why a pulled back volume form is automatically invariant under the action. Let $\omega$ be any volume form on the torus, and let $\psi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a deck transformation. So, by definition, we have$$p\circ\psi=p,$$which yields$$(p\circ\psi)^*\omega=p^*\omega,$$or equivalently,$$\psi^*\left(p^*\omega\right)=p^*\omega.$$

Comment: And why it's automatically invariant under the action? (and thanks this is instructive)

Comment: @Alex I edited, please have a look.

Comment: This is a bit weaselly, "uncountably many" while true, doesn't mean there isn't a distinguished choice which we commonly do, which is what powers the notion of "intuition." It's certainly not ridiculous to call it intuitive given extremely common, standard practices within the community.

Comment: @AdamHughes I beg to differ. While Euclidean space has one standard volume form, the torus has many. In fact, most people who encounter the 2-dimensional torus for the first time, imagine it as a surface embedded in 3-Euclidean space. With this picture in mind, the projection is not volume-preserving at all. Of course, we then equip the torus with the "right" Riemannian metric, which is flat, but this is *highly* non-intuitive for anyone who has always been told that the torus is "a donut", or anything of this sort.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval yes, but he explicitly lists it as $\Bbb R^n/\Bbb Z^n$ it is not some abstract, parametrized torus or other version of the torus.

Comment: @AdamHughes I guess each one of us has his own intuition.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval perhaps, but surely context matters a great deal. I don't disagree that it may not be intuitive to everyone, but the idea that it isn't strongly suggested by context and extremely natural in the common treatment of the subject of induced measures on quotient groups is a bit of a stretch. That is to say: I don't think it's incumbent on everyone (or even just you personally) to *know* that it is common, but I think to say that it being outside the experience area of one makes it uncommon is too much.

Comment: @AdamHughes Still, the word "intuitive" is definitely inappropriately used here. The matter at hand has nothing to do with intuition. Rather, it is an example of a much broader philosophy - universal constructions always come with compatible structures. From this viewpoint, the statement "the projection is volume-preserving" is a tautology.Alternatively, it follows from the construction. The term "intuitive" is more suitable in situations where one prefers to omit a rigorous reasoning. This is not the case with tautologies.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I agree, you've put that well. I drastically reduce the severity of my objection. I think that there is an argument to be made that "based on classical theory and without specific proof" is a good source of intuition for generalizations--as is the case here--but what theory one views as classical may vary sufficiently to make it less so. I still do not think it is priori inappropriate (i.e. it is not definite) but it is reasonable to say it's not clearly intuitive. Thanks for your good discussion.

Comment: I thank you too, @AdamHughes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can observe that $R^n$ is the universal cover, of the torus. This means that the map is locally a homemorphisim. Maybe that what they meant.

Comment: More structure going on here than just the topology.